# Vagrant - does it save machine current state when git push?

Tags: git, github, vagrant, virtualbox

Preety new to vagrant, trying to understand the concept, ok i cloned the project from git, then run `vagrant up`, i made some changes on the machine like database tables creation, and then if I do git push all the commits, does all changes in vagrant development box stay available on next git clone on different machine, if someone else do `vagrant up?`

Comment: Firstly, if you didn't commit anything before you pushed then nothing will get pushed. You probably won't be able to write to the Vagrant repository, so even if you tried to push a commit, it would be rejected. If you want to share configuration with others, you should **fork** the repository so you have your own copy of it, then push your commits and get others to use yours instead of the original.

Answer (score 2):

It would depend what you save in your git repo but generally VMs are not stored within the repo so the answer is no.

The usual workflow is :

1. you git clone a project where there's a `Vagrantfile` defined
2. you might make change to the `Vagrantfile` (box reference, shared project ...) and run `vagrant up`
3. this will build your VM locally
4. you can make change to the VM, destroy, rebuild, etc. all those is done **locally**
5. if you check the changes on of your project, you will see if the VM files are part of the change, but I really doubt it would be and there is no real benefits in doing so.
6. the next person who will clone from your project will inherit the same `vagrantfile` but not the VM content.

If you want to have things done inside the VM (like software installation, DB creation ...) and shared with others, you would need to look at [vagrant provisioning](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/index.html)